# JavaScript regex: capturing optional groups while having a strict matching

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to extract some data from user input that should follow this format: `1d 5h 30m`, which means the user is entering an amount of time of 1 day, 5 hours and 30 minutes.

I am trying to extract the value of each part of the input. However, each group is optional, meaning that `2h 20m` is a valid input.

I am trying to be flexible in the input (in the sense that not all parts need to be input) but at the same time I don't watch my regex to match some random imput like `asdfasdf20m`. This one should be rejected (no match).

So first I am getting rid of any separator the user might have used (their input can look like `4h, 10m` and that's ok):

```
input = input.replace(/[\s.,;_|#-]+/g, '');
```

Then I am capturing each part, which I indicate as optional using `?`:

```
var match = /^((\d+)d)?((\d+)h)?((\d+)m)?$/.exec(input);
```

It is kind of messy capturing an entire group including the letter when I only want the actual value, but I cannot say that cluster is optional without wrapping it with parentheses right?

Then, when an empty group is captured its value in `match` is `undefined`. Is there any function to default `undefined` values to a particular value? For example, `0` would be handy here.

An example where `input` is `"4d, 20h, 55m"`, and the `match` result is:

```
["4d20h55m", "4d", "4", "20h", "20", "55m", "55", index: 0, input: "4d20h55m"]
```

My main issues are:

- How can I indicate a group as optional but avoid capturing it?
- How can I deal with input that can potentially match, like `abcdefg6d8m`?
- How can I deal with an altered order? For example, the user could input `20m 10h`.

When I'm asking "how to deal with x" I mean I'd like to be able to reject those matches.

Comment: You might want to take a look at non capturing groups [`(?:pattern)`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-a-question-mark-followed-by-a-colon).

Comment: As for "How can I deal with an altered order?" how do you *want* to deal with it? Is it `20m 10h` valid or should it be rejected?  How about `4d 5d 6d`? Would it be rejected outright? How about `4D 5H 6M` or `100000m 1s`?

Comment: And what delimiters are allowed? `1d, 1h` is allowed, but is `1d:1h` allowed? How about `1d, 1h,` (trailing delimiter), `1d%1h` or `1d1h`?

Comment: Is an empty string acceptable?

Comment: @Jordan yes, as I think I mentioned it's just an amount of time so `1d 1h` is the same than `1h 1d`. I just threw some common delimiters users might think of using. Only minutes, hours and days are allowed, so `1s` is not allowed, and `1000000m` is allowed too. As of uppercase, sure, I should have added that possibility too.

Comment: @Laurel no, it is not acceptable

Comment: What if the same unit is used multiple times, e.g. `4d 5d 6d`?

Comment: @Jordan not accepted then

Answer (score 0):

As variant:

HTML:

```
<input type="text">
<button>Check</button>
<div id="res"></div>
```

JS:

```
var r = [];
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(){
  var v = document.querySelector('input').value;
  v.replace(/(\d+d)|(\d+h)|(\d+m)/ig, replacer);
  document.querySelector('#res').innerText = r;
}, false);

function trim(s, mask) {
    while (~mask.indexOf(s[0])) {
        s = s.slice(1);
    }
    while (~mask.indexOf(s[s.length - 1])) {
        s = s.slice(0, -1);
    }
    return s;
}

function replacer(str){
  if(/d$/gi.test(str)){
    r[0] = str;
  }
  else if(/h$/gi.test(str)){
    r[1] = str;
  }
  else if(/m$/gi.test(str)){
    r[2] = str;
  }
  return trim(r.join(', '), ',');
}
```

See [here](http://codepen.io/kilotonna/pen/XMrEzq?editors=1010).